# Not able to read newly entered fields in property file in intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have just shifted from eclipse to intellij. I entered some new fields in application.property file but not able to read it. Fields i have entered is showing  with faded colour with text 'unused property. This inspection reports all properties not referenced from outside of the properties file'.

[image]

And i have bind it like this

```
@Value("${invalid_mail}")
private String invalidMail;
```

I am using spring boot.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a `mappings_require` in the `application.property` (Is not it **`application.properties`** ?!). Also, please post the content as code (string) in the post, not an image or it will be probably [downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Yes it is in property file not captured in screen shot.